# Using WSDL With Ruby

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl

I'm getting this error:

```
WSDL::XMLSchema::Parser::UnknownElementError

unknown element: {}HTML
at 'new'
```

when I consume webservices using Ruby. Here is the code snippet:

```
require 'soap/wsdlDriver'

wsdl = url
driver = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(wsdl).create_rpc_driver
driver.options["protocol.http.basic_auth"] << [url, user_name, password]
```

the url points to a well-formed xml.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Can you share the `wsdl` file? Maybe that would help us answering it better.
In any case, I'd suggest generating the Driver classes first using `wsdl2ruby`. And then loding them in your Ruby file (through `require`). Examples (from the man pages):

```
# For server side:
$ wsdl2ruby.rb --wsdl myapp.wsdl --type server
# For client side:
$ wsdl2ruby.rb --wsdl myapp.wsdl --type client
```

Comment: i'm trying to call the lists webservice on sharepoint. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you load the URL in a web browser, does it get redirected to a different location?

In my experience, one reason the error "unknown element: {}HTML" comes up is the WSDL parser is trying to parse the HTML portion of the HTTP redirect and failing to do so. Therefore, you should deal with the redirect yourself (either in code or manually) and give the WSDL driver the final URL.

Comment: Just had exactly this. Some old code that used a http SOAP service started failing, because the service was trying to redirect to a new https-only URL